# Is there a way to make multiline JLabel text flow around the icon?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Currently in my project I have multiple JLabels each with their own text and icon

[image]

The problem I have is that the icon take a whole left side to it self

[image]

The effect I'm trying to achieve is to make the text flow around the icon

[image]

Is this effect possible with JLabel? if not, is it possible with any other component?

Comment: No, a JLabel can't do this, but a JEditorPane might be your best bet

Comment: [Tutorial link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a JLabel and not a JTextArea where the text is editable I would go with an HTMLed JLabel instead of a JEditorPane.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String imageUrl = "https://d1nhio0ox7pgb.cloudfront.net/_img/g_collection_png/standard/512x512/person.png";
    Image sourceImage = ImageIO.read(new URI(imageUrl).toURL()).getScaledInstance(25, 25,
            Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

    //Write the image to disk locally
    File fileWithImage = File.createTempFile("myicon", ".png");
    fileWithImage.deleteOnExit();

    ImageIO.write(toBufferedImage(sourceImage), "png", fileWithImage);

    String lorem = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing<br>"
            + " and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's<br>"
            + " standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer<br>"
            + " took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<br>"
            + " It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic<br>"
            + " typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s<br>"
            + " with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages ";
    String imgTag = "<img src=\"" + fileWithImage.toURI() + "\">";

    final String htmlText = "<html>" + imgTag + " " + lorem;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(htmlText));
}

public static BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image img) {
    if (img instanceof BufferedImage) {
        return (BufferedImage) img;
    }

    BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D bGr = bimage.createGraphics();
    bGr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    bGr.dispose();

    return bimage;
}
```

Run the above example. You will get as result the following image:

[image]

The image conversions depends on how you have the icons but the idea is this. Write the image into a temp file, make it an URI and add it as HTML text to the label.

Comment: That’s the way to go. But if the image originates from another URL, like in your example (and in practice, it almost always does, be it in the internet or embedded in your application’s jar), there is no need to copy it to a temporary file. Even scaling can be done with `img`’s `width` and `height` tag. So in your example, I could simply use `String imgTag = "<img src='" + imageUrl + "' width='25' height='25'>";` and omit the read-scale-create-and-write-temp-file steps. If the image truly is runtime generated without a source URL, you can use the `<object>` tag to get it into the HTML content…

Comment: @Holger yes thats right! I forget it that I already can use the URL. But if I remember correctly, resizing the image with the html tags makes it super low quality. That's why I was biased and exported the resized in a temporary file. I might be mistaken though.

Comment: AWT’s built-in scaling algorithm isn’t the best of the world, but it’s what you get in either case, whether you use `getScaledInstance` or Swing’s Html renderer that most probably even ends up at the same method.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible with any other component?

You can use a `JTextPane`.

It supports an `insertIcon(...)` method which will allow you to insert icons anywhere in the text.

You can make the text pane non editable and transparent to make it look and act more like a JLabel.